# Elixir online IDE/playground website

Tags: elixir

Is there any website which allow to test `Elixir` snippets, save them and share like:

- <del>http://haskellstub.com/</del> *(Dead link)*
- http://ideone.com/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

I find something like:
http://www.tryerlang.org/ and http://try-elixir.herokuapp.com/ but they do not allow to share code, and the second use `Elixir v0.10.2`.

Comment: Not yet, as far as I know. (That's actually something I'm working on, I will update this answer with a link once it's online)

Comment: Another example for PHP: Running a Script in many different PHP Versions and alternative Interpreters. Also supporting sharing of code: http://3v4l.org/39nT5

Comment: Available at http://play.elixirbyexample.com/

Comment: Added to bokmarks

Comment: play.elixirbyexample.com has been down for a while, but I wish it came back, because it was nice, and because of dangling dead links to some (lost?) code.

Comment: Can try jdoodle also

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)

Features:

- Elixir 1.1.0dev
- allow edit in Vim/Emacs mode
- execution of code
- syntax highlighting
- adding extra options to commandline
- sharing links
- other supported languages[
  Bash script    Lazy K
  C
  Lisp
  C#
  Lua
  C++
  PHP
  CPP
  Pascal
  CoffeeScript
  Perl
  D
  Python
  Elixir
  Rill
  Erlang
  Ruby
  Groovy
  Rust
  Haskell
  SQL
  Java
  Scala
  JavaScript
  Vim script]

Example: [Fizzbuzz problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hhDOq9nlBOcLjoKt)

Comment: The link no longer works.

Comment: @iphone007 The website was moved though it still works

Answer (score 12):

I released elixirplayground.com in 2015 but it is no longer active.

Limitations: execution was limited to 5 seconds, networking was disabled, and the filesystem was read-only.

Sharing was implemented via Github Gists. There was a *share* button available that returned a URL, or you could load any gist with the `?gist=gistID` param.

Hope you liked it!

Comment: Unfortunately Elixirplaygrounds is no longer

Answer (score 3):

https://repl.it/ is getting support for elixir soon.

Comment: It does support Elixir now :)

Answer (score 1):

We have recently released https://code.labstack.com, a multi-programming playground with support for [Elixir](https://code.labstack.com/elixir). You can write, run, save, and share programs. I hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Thank you making your online code editor available, I have a question on it. Using pure JS how do you use the input field to retrieve data from the user?  I tried JS functions like prompt() but that is a window library function. @Vishal

Comment: This link is broken!